# Apache Directory indexing does not work in a subdirectory

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, centos7

I have a simple file server (apache 2.4 on centos 7) with following structure:
/index.html - a page to make sure there is no directory listing here
/upload - php scripts for upload
/storage - base dir for files
/storage/upload - files uploaded by php
/storage/public - files that are not password protected

I can't make directory listing work. For example in /storage/public I see the /index.html page. There is no index.html in /storage/public.
If I delete this page I see default apache "testing 123" page in /  page and directory listing works in /storage/public (and all other places that have +Indexes).
Why /index.html is showing in /storage/public/

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot "/home/webroot/www"
  ServerName subdomain.example.com

  ErrorLog "/home/rootdir/log/subdomain.error.log"
  CustomLog "/home/rootdir/log/subdomain.access.log" common

  SuexecUserGroup user apache

#Set caching on image files for 11 months
<filesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|png|js|css)$">
  #ExpiresActive On
  #ExpiresDefault "access plus 11 month"
  Header append Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>

  <Directory "/home/webroot/www" >
    AllowOverride None
    Options -ExecCGI -Indexes +Includes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +MultiViews

    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  <Directory "/home/webroot/www/storage/upload" >
    AllowOverride None
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /home/rootdir/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
      SetHandler "proxy:unix:/usr/local/php73/var/run/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>

  </Directory>
  <Directory "/home/webroot/www/storage/" >
    AllowOverride None
    Options +Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +MultiViews

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /home/rootdir/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    #Require all granted
    RemoveType .php

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/home/webroot/www/storage/public" >
    Options +Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +MultiViews
    AuthType None
    Require all granted
    Satisfy Any
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/home/webroot/www/.well-known" >
    AuthType None
    Require all granted
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/home/webroot/www/storage/upload" >
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /home/rootdir/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
  </Directory>

  <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript
  </IfModule>


Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.example.com/chain.pem

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**Update:**

```
# apachectl -M|grep autoindex
 autoindex_module (shared)
```

Another vhost have the following problem:
there is index.html in root folder for the vhost
I use

```
Options -ExecCGI -Indexes
```

So I have a subdirectory /test and I put another index.html, but when I open /test/ in my browser I see the /index.html instead of /test/index.html

No php in this vhost at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem was that I had changed the global setting from**:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

**to**:

```
DirectoryIndex /index.php index.php /index.html index.html
```

**in an effort to fix another problem** - I use php fpm server with ProxyPassMatch directive like this:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/path/to/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/home/userdir/www/$1
```

As I read on apache.org. The problem with that when using ProxyPassMatch and index.php is missing apache does not load index.html ([another similar problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/553899/forwarding-php-requests-via-proxypassmatch-as-a-handler-or-only-when-file-exist))

Restoring global directive to:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

fixed the problem, but I still have the problem when having ProxyPassMatch in the vhost apache does not fall back to index.html when index.php is missing.

Now I have to award the bounty to someone. If I can't split it between the two answers I'll award it to little_dog because I think he's a bit closer to my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The listed problem gives the impression that there is issues with permissions in the folders involved.

There are several kinds of permissions to be checked:

- process user/group of httpd:

  - use `ps axo pid,user,group,comm`
- file system permissions:

  - users, groups, read-, write-, execute-flags (use `ls -l` and or `ls -lR`, `ls -ld`)
- SELinux permissions:

  - in case it is active, which is likely on CentOS (use `sestatus` to verify status and mode)
  - File Permission contexts (use `ls -lZ` and or `ls -lRZ` `ls -ldZ`)
  - httpd SELinux context (use `ps -axZ | grep httpd`)
  - SELinux booleans (use `getsebool -a | grep httpd`)
  - check audit logs while trying to generate a directory listing (use `tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log`)

Comment: Usually when there is a problem with permissions I get an error. Instead the effect is that I get a index.html from the parent directory. SELinux is disabled (doule checked sestatus shows disabled). I run `chown <user>:apache . -R` in the webroot - everything has the same permissions  (both /index.html and /test/index.html). It more looks like rewrite to me. How do I debug modrewrite.

Comment: Try setting `LogLevel warn rewrite:trace3` in case you suspect rewriting to cause the issue. Also commands like `httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS|DUMP_RUN_CFG|DUMP_MODULES|DUMP_INCLUDES` can be very helpful to understand the full configuration of the webserver.

Comment: I did solve the problem. But I've had problem with mod_rewrite before and I couldn't easily debug it. This could prove useful. Where do I look for the rewrite trace - in access log or error log?

Comment: Seen that after adding the comment. I'm glad you could solve the issue.
I think it is to be found in `CustomLog` after enabling.

Comment: Hmm. it is apache 2.4 only. does not work on apache 2.2

Comment: For 2.2 the following should work: 
`RewriteLogLevel 3`
`RewriteLog "/usr/local/var/apache/logs/rewrite.log`

Comment: Well both answers did not help with finding the solution, but you were more supportive. I won't let the bounty go to waste so I have to award someone so here you are.

Comment: Thank you! I'm happy you could solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have enalbed autoindex module, by: `apachectl -M` should be:

```
Loaded Modules:
...
autoindex_module (shared)
...
```

if its not, you need to to enabled it, in Centos refer to: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258854/disable-and-enable-modules-in-apache-centos7

update #1

for directory listing works, you can't have index.html in your directory, check:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/DirectoryListings

> If no file from the DirectoryIndex directive can be located in the directory, then mod_autoindex can generate a listing of the directory contents.

Comment: autoindex is there, but directory listing is not the main problem. /index.html is shown in subdirectories even if there are different index.html files - see update